# Send Google Ad ID (gclid) to Google Analytics 4 (GA4) using Measurement API

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I want to use the sign_up event as a conversion goal in Google Ads. I'm using Firebase for auth and for sending client-side events to GA4, but it doesn't look like sign_up is sent by Firebase.

I have GA4 configured as a destination in Segment and plan to send the sign_up event server-side to Segment. Segment sends events to GA4 using the [Google Measurement API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events). I need to include the Google Ad ID in the sign_up event so that it is recorded properly as a Google Ads conversion. However, I cannot find anywhere in Google's documentation how to set this parameter. Does anyone know how to set Google Ad ID (gclid) when sending an event using [Google Measurement API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events#sign_up)?

Comment: did you find how to send gclid in gtag? Having the same issue.

Comment: We ended up tracking the signup event client-side using firebase analytics. `firebase.analytics().logEvent("sign_up")`
We also identify the user with firebase client-side:
`firebase.analytics().setUserId(responseBody.userId)`
@vir-us

Comment: @vir us, have you found the solution? The same issue here. Client-side tracking workaround won't work in our case...

Comment: @Skatrix you can try a response in my other question here which I guess might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73020188/reporting-purchases-renewals-to-google-ads-from-server-to-the-initial-user

Answer (score 3):

This is actually set on the Google Ads end. For each account sending traffic to your site, you need to go to the settings (top level) and check the "Enable Auto Tagging" box. This will append the gclid to each ads click.

Alternatively, you can add it as a custom parameter in your campaigns but it's easier to just add it at the account level.

Bear in mind though that if you do enable it, you don't need to pass this back to GA. GA will automatically pick it up for you.

Comment: I enabled auto-tagging and I'm sending my sign_up event server-side. I can see that Google Analytics is counting the sign_up events and attributing them properly to Google Ads via the gclid, so that's great. However, I don't see any conversions recorded in Google Ads yet. Do you know why that might be? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: You need to import the goal from GA into Google Ads as a conversion. 

Did all that answer your question?

Comment: I did all of the above and still not seeing conversions in google ads

Comment: In Google Ads conversion settings (in the Web UI) what is set as your primary conversion action? Also, can you add (and see) the bounce rate column in Google Ads?

Comment: Hey @MaciejCaputa did you manage to solve this issue? I am struggling with the same one.

Comment: After spending countless hours on this issue and getting on numerous calls with Google Support Teams, my issue is still present and unresolved.